# Wrong permissions set on newly created directory

Tags: php, file-permissions

This is the code that creates the "cache" folder with the wrong permissions:

```
mkdir($saveFolder, 02775);
```

When I inspect the folder permissions, using `ls -la`, I receive:

```
drwxr-sr-x
```

But instead I'm expecting:

```
drwxrwsr-x
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For some obscure reasons (at least for me) changing the code to

```
mkdir($saveFolder);
chmod($saveFolder, 02775);
```

solved the issue.

Now I get the right permissions set on the folder:

```
drwxrwsr-x
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks

Comment: Unless you're using something I'm unfamiliar with, you shouldn't need the 0 prefix, 2775 should be good enough.

Answer (score 2):

Your current umask also affects the mode so depending on your umask settings, the mode of the created directory may not match the octal specified in your function call.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php:

> The mode is 0777 by default, which means the widest possible access. For more information on modes, read the details on the chmod() page. Note that you probably want to specify the mode as an octal number, which means it should have a leading zero. ***The mode is also modified by the current umask, which you can change using umask()***.

Try setting `umask(0)` and the argument supplied to `mkdir()` should work as expected.

More discussion here: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65796

Comment: chmod with leading zero, solved my problem. Thanks mate